# How to properly delete wxWidgets Window?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

Sorry if my question is a bit off base, I am kinda new to developing software, I got a project to develop a native Windows application that will be cross-platform later on. They told me to work with wxWidgets but I have been having trouble with the usage of mpWindows.

The issue right now being that I am creating a new Screen when I press a button, and that Screen contains a Mathplot, when I go and close the screen it give me a segmentation fault. I tried using the gdb to find the problem but no luck so far, I am not that experienced using it for this type of development. In the screen I literally only have the declaration of the mpWindow and the setting up of the margins. Would you need pictures to have a better idea? In the close event I am calling this->Destroy(); because this->Close fails to terminate the screen

Thank you in advance and sorry for the long post.

Btw I am using Code::Blocks, GCC 7.2, and wxWidgets 3.1.0

Comment: I understand by "Screen" you mean a window. The `Close()` function is available to all wxWindow-derived controls and it does close the window, removes its children, its pointer and other clean-up. Using `Destroy()` is very rare. See [docs](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/overview_windowdeletion.html). Have you taken a look at *samples/minimal*?

Comment: Yes I mean a window, and yes I read the docs that is why I am a bit confused. It is simply deleting an object and still can't seem to find why it is giving a segmentation fault. My guess was that deleting the mpWindow (Mathplot) needed a process but can't seem to make it work.

Comment: Compile wx and your app with debugging symbols (pass `-g` to the compiler or set it at C:B project settings). Then `gdb` can understand it and so offer break points, stack trace, running step by step, etc.

Comment: I'll try that thanks I appreciate the time